# DBMS_RANDOM doesn't seem to work

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, oracle

I am still fairly new to Oracle SQL here, but I have scoured the internet to be able to just randomly pull a row from a table and saw a code like this.

```
firstNameGen = connection.prepareStatement(
    "SELECT firstName "
        +"FROM (SELECT firstName "
        +"FROM firstNames "
        +"ORDER BY dbms_random.value) "
    +"WHERE ROWNUM = 1");
```

It is not working for me. Obviously, I did change all the column and table names to match my own database, but it just tells me "ERROR 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "WHERE" at line 1, column 58."

I'm working in Eclipse. Do I need to import the functionality to use dbms_random or am I just missing something? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That looks fine, so maybe you lost the problem (like a missing space or parenthesis) while changing the names; can you post your original query instead? That doesn't look like a native Oracle error though, so maybe you have a middle layer that doesn't like the subquery syntax?

Comment: have you waited for the result? some times it takes some minutes to get results when using `ORDER BY dbms_random.value`

Comment: The statement is syntactically correct. So I guess it is not Oracle complaining about the syntax, but some Java db layer getting it wrong.

Comment: Works fine for me in Oracle 11.1. What version of Oracle are you querying against?

Comment: Waiting for the result is out. The program terminates with the error.

I have Oracle version 12c Release 1, which I believe is the most up to date.

The only thing I see that might be a problem is on the documentation page, it says that DBMS_RANDOM should be installed by SYS. I don't actually know what that is referring to. Here is a link to the documentation, though.

[link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_random.htm#ARPLS040)

Comment: @henryr0923 you are right, I didn't attend that the program gives error, I only thought that it doesn't work (question title).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an Oracle DB error code (they start with `ORA-` or `ERR-` or `TNS-`). It does look like a Derby error code. So did you use the wrong driver to access your oracle database, or do you actually mean JavaDB with "Oracle Database"? I guess the syntax is not valid for Derby/JavaDB.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15914365/13189), the following syntax would work:

```
"SELECT firstName FROM firstNames ORDER BY RANDOM() OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY"
```

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure but order by dbms_random.value `may` not working properly when using extra layers for example jdbc. also when you order by `<expression returning a number>`, `it orders by the expression`, not a "column"  however you want only one value to display, I can say two alternate ways:

1. Just add the dbms_random.value as a column to the query and order by that.

   ```
   select * from (select
     firstName 
     , dbms_random.value as ran
   from firstNames
   order by ran)
   where rownum=1;
   ```
2. use sample()

   ```
   select firstName
   from firstNames sample (1)
   where rownum =1;
   ```

Comment: Neither alternative will work correctly.  The first one will evaluate the `rownum` before the `order by` and will likely return the same value every time.  The second one will work a little better, but will still tend to return some values over others because of the way data is retrieved pseudo-ordered by `sample`.  Although using `sample` in combination with another random ordering may dramatically improve performance so it's an idea worth considering.

Comment: I've seen that syntax before, but whenever I execute, it tells me that dbms_random.value isn't a column in my table. With the second script, using sample, I get a similar error to my original problem: ERROR 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "1" at line 1, column 41.

Comment: @JonHeller Both alternate works correctly, however thanks for the comment, I edited the first one, now it `order` it before evaluating `rownum`

Comment: @henryr0923, for me the both working properly, now I'm sure for you the problem is with the settings of dbms_random, I can't say more and you researched about it more and know more than me, If you found something share it with us also, anyway I hope you'll get it solved.

Comment: #1 is fixed but #2 still doesn't work for me.  Try this code, and run the select multiple times; the results are very non-random: `create table test1(a number); insert into test1 select level from dual connect by level <= 100000; select a from test1 sample(1) where rownum = 1;`